# Server side projection with MongoDB C# driver 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, projection

I have a collection of documents with a few small properties, and one huge property (a binary 10MB or so PDF document). I'm using the latest stable C# driver, published on 2015-04-02. Is there a way to get a list of these documents, with all the small properties, but excluding the huge binary one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to use `IFindFluent.Find` and then use `IFindFluent.Projection` and `Builders.Projection.Exclude` to exclude this property:

```
var query = collection.
    Find(filter).
    Project<Document>(Builders<Document>.Projection.Exclude(doc => doc.HugeBlob));
var results = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I read somewhere that projection is client side and doesnt affect the load that returns from thr mongoDb..can you confirm this happens on mongo's side?

Comment: @OriRefael yes. You can also see the eventual server-side query with `query.ToString`.

Comment: @i3arnon - Can you please answer the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801269/step-by-step-single-where-clause-query-in-a-embedded-document-of-mongodb-collect/37802879?noredirect=1#comment63070962_37802879